# Flask SQLAlchemy not returning expected result

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I'm very new to Flask and am having trouble getting my models to work correctly. I've gone through quite a few links and tutorials in search for this answer, but have failed to connect the dots. So I'm hoping someone will point out the mistake here.

My requirement is simple: My app maintains tables for websites and their categories, and I'm currently trying SQLAlchemy to give me a list of all categories along with their websites.

Here are my models:

```
class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "categories"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    websites = db.relationship('Website', backref='category')

class Website(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "websites"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    url = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    class_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
```

And here's how I'm using these:

```
categories = Category.query.all()

for cat in categories:
    print('*' * 20)
    print(cat.websites)
    print('*' * 20)
    print(dir(cat.websites))
```

These print statements are there because `cat.websites` wasn't giving me the websites I was looking for. Here's a sample output for one of the loop passes:

```
********************
[<models.Website object at 0x7f7cde94e7b8>]
********************
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_sa_adapter', '_sa_appender', '_sa_converter', '_sa_instrumented', '_sa_iterator', '_sa_remover', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

So even though I have a list of model objects in the output, its `dir()` listing shows none of the attributes I'm interested in, i.e., `websites`. Even more interestingly, adding `print(cat.websites[0])` to the function throws an `IndexError`. Why?

There is data in the database (MySQL), but why is it not getting captured as desired?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out myself eventually. We need to have `lazy='dynamic'` defined in the relationship.